# How to parse a Breeze SaveBundle

Tags: breeze

I'm using breeze with EF and doing server side validation in the ContextProvider in BeforeSaveEntity and BeforeSaveEntities.  That's working but I'm looking for a way to do this validation at a higher level, preferably before the request hits the controller.

I already have a custom http module where all requests are going through.  I'm doing some logging and authentication in the custom http module.  My goal is to also add some authorization validation at the same time/place.

Let's say I have a user that is updating his profile record.  I have his identity in my auth cookie/token.  The profile ID (Database PK) is embedded in the JSON passed in the request body.  I can't assume the user didn't maliciously change this profile ID value to another value on the client before sending.  So I want to pluck out this ID and validate that it is the ID for this user.

I'm getting the request input stream as a JSON string in my http module.  In this string is all the breeze stuff:  entities array, entity aspects, and of course, the ID I'm looking for.

Are there any helper utilities that can assist me in parsing this json string?  either by pulling out specific values based on entity and property name?  Or even reconstructing the objects contained in the bundle?

Thanks

Comment: Nobody?  Server-side validation is so crucial, how are others handling it?  BeforeSaveEntity and BeforeSaveEntities?  That works but a lot of processing takes place before you even get there.

Answer (score 0):

Took a look at the breeze [SaveChanges code](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/Breeze.ContextProvider/ContextProvider.cs#L59-L63).  It uses a public class called `SaveWorkState` which is constructed using two arguments:  a `ContextProvider` and a `JArray`.  The content of the JArray is the "entities" property in the JSON sent to the server during the savechanges.

Once the `SaveWorkState` is constructed you can access the `EntityInfo` objects via the `EntityInfoGroups` property.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var serializerSettings = BreezeConfig.Instance.GetJsonSerializerSettings();
var jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
var saveBundle = ... JObject constructed from the JSON posted to your controller ...;
var dynSaveBundle = (dynamic)saveBundle;
var entitiesArray = (JArray)dynSaveBundle.entities;
var contextProvider = ... EFContextProvider<> ...;
var saveWorkState = new SaveWorkState(contextProvider, entitiesArray);
var entityInfoGroups = saveWorkState.EntityInfoGroups;  // <- this is what you want.
```